# Keras the specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow, keras, import

I am getting this error on Keras.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found while importing Keras
```

What I tried?

```
-initially "conda install -c conda-forge keras" 
-then i also followed the tensorflow install instructions on tensorflow website
-I tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ that did not solve
-Also downloaded a msvcp140_1.dll file and pasted it in the sys32 and syswow64 of windows folder,did not help
-while importing the tensorflow it is reflecting the same problem
-OS-MSW-8.1


import keras
Error in callback <bound method AutoreloadMagics.post_execute_hook of <autoreload.AutoreloadMagics object at 0x0000006394266548>> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you installed all redistributables?

Comment: Hi,Mr.Lukasz Tracewski ,After reading your question, i realised i have downloaded the redistributable 2015 ,So I went back and re-installed the latest i.e 2019 redistributable and it helped me get through the problem. Thank you! ,for your bringing on track question.

Comment: I am glad it worked! I posted this as the answer so that others can easily find it. Consider accepting it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in comments, the OP was missing some of the Visual Studio redistributables. After installing appropriate (in terms of architecture) `vc_redist` from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) everything worked fine.